# Is it possible to use XAML for my own ideas / framework?

Tags: xaml, xamlreader

Do you know if it would be possible to create a framework myself in C# that utilizes the good things that XAML offers, such as dependency properties and data binding?

Or would I have to create everything from scratch myself?

Answer (score 1):

You can use XAML for many (any?) object initialization needs. DataBinding and DPs are really a WPF feature, which of course you can re-use